# How to get info from a listbox populated by an SQL query?

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access, listbox, vba

The title says the vague question, but, I will be more specific. I'm more of a hardware oriented person with some experience in VB, Java, and C++. I've been asked to modify a form in Access which uses SQL queries to take information from a database. The edit I am trying to make is to a form that has selections to narrow down the data it queries from to appear in a listbox in the center of the form (so, like radio buttons to specify a certain height or weight of an object in the database). The selections, as they are selected, concatenate additional specifications to an string that is then run as an SQL query. What I am trying to accomplish is to take a column of the narrowed-down data and find the maximum number in the column and the average of the numbers in the column. It seems really simple and know how to do that with regular lists and arrays, but I'm at a loss with my limited knowledge. I've considered making another SQL string, but in another part of the form, it was done with two strings (so, one to put the data in the listbox from the database and one to pull the specific column of the narrowed down data). That being said, it doesn't seem logical to me to pull the same sets of data each time, so I'm wondering if I can just pull the info from the already pulled info. At the bottom of the code set is this:

```
ItemList.RowSource = vSQLStock
ItemList = Null
ItemList.Requery

QuoteList.RowSource = vSQLNonStock
QuoteList = Null
QuoteList.Requery
```

Both vSQLStock and vSQLNonStock have their own sets of SQL strings that are run by this function, or as far as I can tell (I'm still studying up on SQL) put the narrowed down items in the QuoteList listbox. What I'm asking is if there is a way with any function that can be used to go through this information? Specifically, take a column and do some calculations on the data. I don't want to run another SQL query and bog down the server, but rather manipulate the data on the user's computer.

*An example of what happens is the user selects whether the item is stock/nonstock, searches by the name/code/ID, and then puts all the matches on the listbox on the form. The listbox shows lines of data with columns like Name, Cost, Size, Weight, etc. of which I am looking to do calculations on the Cost column. Hopefully this is enough information; I appreciate any advice.*

Answer (score 0):

It looks from your question like you are attempting to get the Maximum and the Average from a SQL query.

the syntax:

```
SELECT MAX(myColumn) as MyMax, AVG(myColumn) as MyAverage
FROM   myTable
WHERE  . . .
```

Will return the Maximum and Average Values within SQL Server or within MS Access

Answer (score 0):

If you're really bound and determined to do this locally with the data you've already retrieved from the server, then you probably need to look into working with adodb.recordsets. You can kind of treat it like an array. Kind of.

I really recommend querying the server for the data you need though. It's a world simpler.

```
dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = QuoteList.Recordset

rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
    ' loop through recordset doing something
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```